# Launching mongosh in VS code

Tags: javascript, database

I want to launch mongodb shell in VS code and the error is "the term **mongosh** is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet." Is working perfectly in mongodb command line.
I have set both user and system environment variable

I have downloaded mongodb extension. I'm trying to run mongodb shell in VS code but is responding with error "the term mongosh is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.